# How to await for incoming message using puppeteer using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

This is the code to send automated messages in a loop. How to await for new message and then send a message?

````
let scrape = async (url)=>{                                         //scraping function
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});
    const page= await browser.newPage();
   await  page.goto(url);
    await page.waitForSelector("span[title='xyz']");

   const target=await page.$("span[title='xyz']");      //selecting target user

  await  target.click();
    const inp=await page.$("#main > footer > div._3ee1T._1LkpH.copyable-area > div._3uMse > div > div._3FRCZ.copyable-text.selectable-text");
    for(let i=0;i<2;i++){
        inpMessage();              //input message details        
       
    }

}

function inpMessage(){                 //input message function call
    await inp.type("hi");
       
        await page.keyboard.press("Enter");
}

scrape('https://web.whatsapp.com/');         //function call```
````

Comment: make `inpMessage` function `async`  function and await the `inpMessage` function in for loop.

Comment: but i want to await for incoming message(the message from front side)